# Git add on modified file not working, except with -p (patch)

Tags: git, git-add

After the first two hours of working all of the sudden, I can't seem to `git add` one file.

```
Casper@PC2015 MINGW64 /c/Workspace/edoping (develop)
$ git add .

Casper@PC2015 MINGW64 /c/Workspace/edoping (develop)
$ git status
    On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   app/Http/Controllers/API/AuthController.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I have tried a lot if ways to add without success:

- `git add .`
- `git add <path-to-file>`
- `git add -f <path-to-file>`
- `git add --all`
- `git commit -a`

---

So I also have checked if I have submodules (which would be without me knowing about it). And I didn't seem to have those either.
To find them I did:

- `git config --file .gitmodules --name-only --get-regexp path`
- `grep path .gitmodules | sed 's/.*= //'`
- `git submodule status --recursive`.

---

I also looked into the `.gitignore` file, but this is still the default `.gitignore` from `Laravel 5.3`

---

`git diff` shows the changes made to the file like normal

```
Casper@PC2015 MINGW64 /c/Workspace/edoping (develop)
$ git diff
diff --git a/app/Http/Controllers/API/AuthController.php b/app/Http/Controllers/API/AuthController.php
index 9bfe453..5add519 100644
--- a/app/Http/Controllers/API/AuthController.php
+++ b/app/Http/Controllers/API/AuthController.php
@@ -65,7 +65,12 @@ class AuthController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller {
     public function register(Request $request) {

         $this->validate($request, [
-            'email' => 'unique:users,email'
+            'email'      => 'unique:users,email',
+            'first_name' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
+            'last_name'  => 'required|min:2|max:255',
+            'password'   => 'required|min:2|max:255',
+            'avatar'     => 'required',
+            'birthdate'  => 'required',
         ]);
```

---

`.gitattributes` doesn't show anything different from the Laravel defaults either.

```
* text=auto
*.css linguist-vendored
*.scss linguist-vendored
```

---

There are no nested repositories:

```
Casper@PC2015 MINGW64 /c/Workspace/edoping (develop)
$ find -name .git
./.git
```

---

`git add -p` gives me the following output.

```
Casper@PC2015 MINGW64 /c/Workspace/edoping (develop)
$ git add -p
diff --git a/app/Http/Controllers/API/AuthController.php b/app/Http/Controllers/API/AuthController.php
index 9bfe453..5add519 100644
--- a/app/Http/Controllers/API/AuthController.php
+++ b/app/Http/Controllers/API/AuthController.php
@@ -65,7 +65,12 @@ class AuthController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller {
     public function register(Request $request) {

         $this->validate($request, [
-            'email' => 'unique:users,email'
+            'email'      => 'unique:users,email',
+            'first_name' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
+            'last_name'  => 'required|min:2|max:255',
+            'password'   => 'required|min:2|max:255',
+            'avatar'     => 'required',
+            'birthdate'  => 'required',
         ]);

         $request->only($this->user_fillable);
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,j,J,g,e,?]?
```

When responding with `y`, the file does get added to the index.

---

Why does `git add -p` work, while all other methods described above do not?

**EDIT**:
So I tried to commit some changes again, but I did find something new. `Git` seems to think there are two folders inside `app/Http/Controllers/`, which are `Api` and `API`. But there is only `API`.

Around a thousand commits back I did change the folders name from `Api` to `API` because I had to from my senior. Could this be the origin of the problem?

```
Casper@PC2015 MINGW64 /c/Workspace/edoping (develop)
$ gs
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   app/Http/Controllers/API/AuthController.php
        modified:   app/Http/Controllers/Api/AuthController.php
```

Comment: What did Git say, when you try `git add`?

Comment: @MartinZhai , nothing

Comment: Any chance a `.gitignore` rule applies to the file in question?

Comment: No checked that already @domdom

Comment: You don't need to include an edit log in the question, it's already accessible using the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42552432/revisions).

Comment: `git diff` outputs anything?

Comment: @MartinZhai yes it displays the changes made to the file, just like normal

Comment: I have seen behavior somewhat like this with odd CRLF mappings, but they should not be *that* persistent. You might check whether you have CRLF conversions set up in your configuration and/or your `.gitattributes` file, though. Meanwhile I noticed one other peculiarity in your prompt: one says `@PC2015` and the other `@MPC2015`, where did the M come from or go to?

Comment: @torek checked the `.gitattributes` and added it to the post, I think that's also Laravel's standard?

Comment: Does `git add -p` prompt you to stage the changes shown by `git diff`?

Comment: I've had the same kind of issue after someone cloned an other git repo inside of the one I was working on

Comment: Do you by any chance have nested Git repositories (`find <top level> -name .git` would show more than one result)?

Comment: OK, it's definitely not just CRLF issues, and it's definitely odd. (Though as ZeenaZeek and mkrieger1 suggested, it's worth checking for nested repositories.)

Comment: @torek @mkrieger1 @ZeenaZeek I edited the post with a search for nested git repositories. Disclaimer: didn't find anything except the main `.git`.

Comment: So `git add -p` * does*  recognize the changes. What happens if you respond with `y` (yes)? Will the file finally be added to the index?

Comment: @mkrieger1 so `git add -p` worked for me, but I am interested in why this worked and a normal `git add` did not. Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Good question ;)

Comment: @mkrieger1 so I might have found the origin of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying a lot of different things I was able to add the changes.

What I did:

- `git add -p` which will output a prompt.
- `Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,K,j,J,g,e,?]?`.
- I answered `y` for every change and at the end of the file, it was added.
- After this I was able to `commit` and `push` the changes.

---

Thank you all for the help and [@mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621513/mkrieger1) for coming with `git add -p`